# Windows Store can't install any application with Error code: 0x8007002

Tags: windows-8, crash, modern-ui, windows-store

Before some-time my metro-apps stopped running - whatever I start one it then immediately closes. I then uninstalled all user-apps and was able to fix the system ones - as store, metro control panel and camera using this [guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/notime/archive/2013/10/21/10458031.aspx). But now I can't install any user-application from the store always giving me the error "This app can't be installed - 0x8007002". I figured out that this have something to do with the application deployment as I have debugged an example which installs APX packages which was failing with the same error. It was easy to observe that the [PackageManager.AddPackageAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br240961.aspx). However debugging an WinRT interface is impossibly hard compared to the lot simpler Win32 API's (you can't believe how much code is invoked from just the simplest WinRT method call) and as far as I have being doing this (2 days so far) I wasn't able to find where this *** error arises. But anyway - I could post another question in stack-exchnage for it. So here are the things I've tried by now (as far IIRC):

Deleting "Programs\WindowsApps" folder.

Deleting some of the files in the "User\AppData\Local\Packages" (when I deleted the whole folder Windows Store won't open).

Tried all kind of troubleshooters.

Perofrmed sfc scan & dism too.

Tried "clean-boot".

"WsReset.exe" - with no result - windows store almost immidiately loads.

Sorry if you can't understand some of my thoughts but I'm writing secretly from my parents now at 1:22 AM. Tomorrow I could edit the question.

If you can suggest something - please do it but I won't accept windows reinstall, repair, refresh or such things.

Also I'm using Win8.1 x64 UEFI with latest updates & Secure Boot.

Also I can kernel-debug the PC if needed.

Answer (score 1):

*Try clearing the Windows Store Cache:
1.  Right Click the Start screen (bottom left hand corner).
2.  Click on Run OR just Windows+R.
3.  Type **WSReset.exe** and press Enter.

Comment: I also tried this but forgot to mention. When I click it Windows Store almost immediately launch. I remember that before it took like 15 mins to load.